# my custom method to get Arraylist from adapter in activity does not return Arraylist like expcted

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have Arraylist (`list_cart`) that is created inside Adapter (`OrderAdapter.java`) which I want to access from its Parent activity.

I read that I need to create a custom method to get it.

Here is the method : `public ArrayList<Cart> getArrayList(){ return list_cart; }`

And to access it I write these codes in my Activity :

```
btnUpdateTotal.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            OrderAdapter orderAdapter = new OrderAdapter();
            ArrayList<Cart> myCart = orderAdapter.getArrayList();
            int total =  myCart.size();
            tvTotalCart.setText("Total in cart : "+String.valueOf(total));
        });
```

however the `int total` returns 0 instead of the size of the Arrays. There is no error, just the result from debugging says `size = 0`

Here is the Debug result :

```
orderAdapter : OrderAdpater@12429
context = null
list_cart = null
list_barang = {ArrayList @12448} size = 0
```

I'm still new to Passing Array from adapter to activity, so please help me.

To make sure if my `list_cart` is not empty, I checked the size from **inside the adapter** and it does return the number corresponding to the array size

**Here is my OrderAdapter class**

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
public class OrderAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<OrderAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<Barang> list_barang;
    public ArrayList<Cart> list_cart = new ArrayList<Cart>();// this is what I need to access from activity
    private Context context;

public OrderAdapter(ArrayList<Barang> list_barang, Context context){
    this.list_barang = list_barang;
    this.context = context;
}

public OrderAdapter() {

}

public ArrayList<Cart> getArrayList(){return list_cart;}

@NonNull
@Override
public OrderAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    context = parent.getContext();

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_add_penjualan2, parent, false);

    return new OrderAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
}

@SuppressLint({"DefaultLocale", "SetTextI18n"})
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull OrderAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position){
   ... the ViewHolder codes..
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() { return list_barang.size(); }


public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    ... the variables declaration ...

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView){
        super(itemView);
        ... the initialize ...
    }

    public void actionItem(int position){
       btnTambah.setOnClickListener(view -> {
           Cart cart = new Cart();
           Barang myBarang = list_barang.get(position);

           String productId = myBarang.getID();
           String productName = myBarang.getTitle();
           double productHarga = myBarang.getHarga();
           int qty = Integer.parseInt(etQtyBarang.getText().toString());

           cart.setProductID(productId);
           cart.setProductName(productName);
           cart.setHarga(productHarga);
           cart.setQty(qty);
           list_cart.add(cart);// This is the ArrayList that I want to access from Parent Activity
       });
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this line in your activity

```
OrderAdapter orderAdapter = new OrderAdapter(list_barang, Context);
btnUpdateTotal.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        ArrayList<Cart> myCart = orderAdapter.getArrayList();
        int total =  myCart.size();
        tvTotalCart.setText("Total in cart : "+String.valueOf(total));
    });
```

Comment: it's still not working. I still don't get the size of the Array, that means it failed to return the array right?